# Does a HTTP Get on a File in Azure Blob Storage return Meta Data in Http Headers?

Tags: azure

AFAIK you can associate custom meta data with Blobs in Azure Blob Storage. Will a HTTP Get return that Meta Data in the Http Response Headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179440.aspx).

> Reads or downloads a blob from the system, including its metadata and properties.